# Why there's two python versions in my lib folder?

Tags: python, debian

I have just installed a python virtual environment in my Debian 4.19.132-1 (Python3.8) via

```
python3 -m venv myapp
```

and noticed the following; inside my lib folder (myapp/lib) there are two subfolders, python3.8 and python3.7.

If I use commands like

```
pip install
```

the module will be installed in **myapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages**. But if I run

```
python
```

the version that'll be running is the 3.7.3. In this case, I have to use

```
python3.8
```

to have access to the right version.

My question here is, if I used my 3.8 installation to create a virtual environment, what does this 3.7 version is doing there? And there is some way to remove it to no let it cause malfunctions in my programs?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Result of `dpkg -l python3`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=========================================================================
ii  python3        3.7.3-1      amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
```

Result of `type -all python3`

```
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
```

Relevant results of `ls -l`

```
drwxr-xr-x 18 gabriel_fernandes google-sudoers        4096 Oct  7 14:14 Python-3.8.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root              root              17869888 Oct  7 13:06 Python-3.8.2.tar.xz
```

Comment: Any chance `myapp` already existed from a previous venv created with the other version of python?

Comment: Did you install two Python versions in the first place, and if so how, and which one is system-supplied? In other words, please [edit] to include the output from `dpkg -l python3`, `type -all python3`, and `ls -l` on the paths that this command prints. For a start.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the fast response! just edited the post to contemplate the results. I don't know exactly how the system configuration was made, since I got the machine pre-configured.

Comment: @tdelaney not actually friend! this is the first time using venvs in this machine; the other user just called the methods upon the root installation

Comment: That doesn't look like the `ls -l` of `/usr/bin/pyhon3` but it does indicate that someone installed 3.8 separately somehow. I'm guessing your `/usr/bin/python3` remains 3.7 and that 3.8 is somewhere like `/opt/python3/bin/python3` (or maybe `/usr/local/bin/python3`; but then it should be on your `PATH`, and listed byt`type -all`). Is that a listing of yoqr home directory? Can you talk to the people who initialized this machine for you? Do you have an alternative package manager like Anaconda in addition to `dpkg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like somebody installed Python 3.8 alongside Python 3.7 but forgot to rename `pip` so the new one takes precedence over the system-installed 3.7 one.

In some more detail, Debian out of the box ships Python 3.7 in `/usr/bin/python3` but for Python development you also want to have the latest and greatest version, which somebody seems to have installed from source, probably somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`.

If that `pip` version is `/usr/local/bin/pip` (rather than, say, `/usr/local/bin/pip3.8`) it will shadow the system `pip` in `/usr/bin/pip` which is for 3.7 (also depending on your `PATH`, but conventionally `/usr/local/bin` takes precedence over `/usr/bin`).

We can't tell for sure why this was done this way, but it seems the naming of `pip` (or rather, failure to rename the new version so it doesn't shadow) was a mistake. In sane organizations, you would have a supervisor or mentor who could tell you what you are supposed to do with this computer, and perhaps point to some documentation if this is something the organization does systematically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the directions! I was not aware that Debian has an out of the box version of python, I think this explains the problem, since I could not find any other installation in my home directory. Is there a simple way to change the pip path within the system? Thanks again!

Comment: Again, without details, it's hard to say anything specific. Probably.

Comment: If it's in `/usr/local/bin/pip` then maybe rename that to `/usr/local/bin/pip3.8` but this whole deal with two separate Pythons is slightly hard to manage. Maybe look into `pipenv` for keeping each Python version and its support utilities and libraries separate.